# Позиционно-независимое получение адреса переменной

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Задача - дописать код до рабочего состояния.

```
some_var dd ?
... // код
// здесь мы имеем в регистре eax, к примеру, адрес переменной some_var
```

Решение очевидно - `lea eax, [some_var]`, однако оно не устраивает меня по той причине, что не является position-independent (на русский попытался перевести в заголовке вопроса). Иначе говоря, мне нужен код, который можно вместе с данными скопипастить по любому адресу и получить его же в рабочем состоянии. Переменные обязаны были глобальными.

Моё решение основано на том, что разность между адресами меток не зависит от позиции кода. Во время компиляции можно узнать адреса меток для фиксированного адреса размещения кода, а реальную его позицию после переноса - с помощью `call $+5`, `pop eax`. Сейчас я так и выкручиваюсь, но полученный код слишком громоздкий. С другой стороны, на исходном коде это не отражается, так как завернуто в макрос.

Вопрос - есть ли решение проще? Использую fasm, возможно его препроцессор способен на это.

---

Мой вариант

```
    call $+5
label:
    lea eax, [label]
    sub [esp], eax
    lea eax, [var]
    add [esp], eax
    pop eax
```

Comment: Добавьте еще код, который у вас получился, в вопрос.

Comment: По-моему достаточно call $+5; pop eax; add eax, some_var - $ - 1. Проверить, правда, сейчас не могу.

Comment: У меня, к сожалению, тоже нет возможности проверить. Код свой по памяти дописал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня получился примерно такой код:

```
format PE console
include 'win32ax.inc'

entry start

section '.data' data readable writeable
rb 7 ; Отступаем от начала секции на 7 байт, просто чтобы адрес переменной не был "ровным"
some_var dd ?
_fmt db '%p',13,10,0

section '.code' code readable executable
start:
    mov eax, some_var
    cinvoke printf, _fmt, eax ; Эталонный адрес, в моем случае 00401007

    call label1 ; Переход на следующую команду, в стек кладется адрес возврата, равный адресу label1
label1:
    pop eax ; Получаем адрес возврата из стека
    sub eax, label1 - some_var ; Уменьшаем адрес на разницу адресов переменной и метки label1
    ; Разница label1 - some_var вычисляется в момент компиляции
    cinvoke printf, _fmt, eax ; Вычисленный адрес: 00401007

    invoke ExitProcess, 0

section '.idata' import data readable

library kernel, 'kernel32.dll', \
    msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll'

import kernel,\
    ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess'

import msvcrt,\
    printf,'printf'



section '.idata' import data readable

library kernel, 'kernel32.dll', \
    msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll'

import kernel,\
    ExitProcess, 'ExitProcess'

import msvcrt,\
    printf,'printf'
```

В виде макроса:

```
macro get_addr var
{
    local ..label1
    call ..label1
..label1:
    pop eax
    sub eax, ..label1 - var
}
```

`local` нужно чтобы при подстановке макроса каждый раз генерировались новые имена метки. Две точки перед именем метки делают метку глобальной, но не становящейся родительской меткой для локальных меток (начинающихся с одной точки).

После вызова макроса адрес переменной будет находиться в регистре eax.

Comment: Спасибо. Не знал про метки, видимые внутри макроса (приходилось через @@ делать) и про явное вычитание адресов, вычисляемое во время компиляции.

Comment: @int3, вам нужно хотя бы раз бегло пролистать мануал по fasm полностью, пусть не все понять (я вот так до конца и не постиг дзен макросов), но хотя бы представлять, какой функционал предоставляет компилятор.

Comment: постепенно узнаю новое, мануалы периодически листаю. Кстати, трюк с .. не сработал, пришлось в макрос дописывать `local label_name`, чтобы скрыть из видимости вне макроса.

Comment: @int3, да, правильно, нужно local использовать, сейчас поправлю ответ.